# iMac freezes and requires manual shutdown

Tags: macos, imac

The iMac is freezing. We have to shut it off manually. I have done as much as I can do, I'm at a loss.

Just ran a virus scan and while it was scanning, I noted that 3 printers are still on this computer, however, I haven't a clue where they are to uninstall, so I will need help with this issue, too. The scan came out clean.

This computer is used for downloading photos from 2 different cameras, word processing, email, web, iTunes. Games are not played at all.

Comment: Is reinstalling an option?

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the the PRAM/NVRAM [instructions here](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT1379).

Then try resetting the SMC [instructions here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3964).

If those don't work, do this for Lion or Mountain Lion:

Start the iMac using the recovery option - this is generally either Command + R or Option + R. Hold one of those down right after you hit the power button and you should boot in to a recovery mode. Once in recovery mode do something - like open a terminal and run top so see what's running. Wait. If the computer overheats and shuts down you have a hardware issue - take it to the store. If it doesn't, it's most likely a software issue - backup and reinstall.

Just a note, I contacted Apple a few weeks ago and they had me do PRAM/SMC reset. My fans in my macbook wouldn't stop spinning afterwards. The tech had no idea what was going on. I reset the PRAM/SMC *again*, but this time in reverse order - the fan stopped and everything was back to normal. Unfortunately, I forgot the sequence of events...